# Use custom where condition with JDBI dropwizard

Tags: java, sql, dropwizard, jdbi

I am trying to explore JDBI with dropwizard, my custome code is as below.

```
public interface UserDao {
@SqlQuery("SELECT FROM `t_user` :cond")
@Mapper(UserMapper.class)
List<User> fetch(@Bind("cond") String cond);
}
```

and trying to call with below code

```
Application.getJdbi().onDemand(UserDao.class).fetch("where logon_id="+p.getEmail()+"'");
```

and getting below issue

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM `t_user` 'where logon_id=sanjaypatel2525@gmail.com\''' at line 1
```

I am getting quotes issues as this is been passed as String. This way I am trying to achieve common where clause code for all the queries.
My questions are
1. How to resolve this issue.
2. Is this is proper way to code like this, or we can use prepared statement. If yes then how.

Great Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use Define instead of Bind for dynamic queries.

```
public interface UserDao {
 @SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM t_user :cond")
 @Mapper(UserMapper.class)
 List<User> fetch(@Define("cond") String cond);
}
```

Comment: Tried and getting error
org.skife.jdbi.v2.exceptions.UnableToExecuteStatementException: Unable to execute, no named parameter matches "cond" and no positional param for place 0 (which is 1 in the JDBC 'start at 1' scheme) has been set. [statement:"SELECT FROM `t_user` :cond", located:"SELECT FROM `t_user` :cond", rewritten:"/* UserDao.fetch */ SELECT FROM `t_user` ?", arguments:{ positional:{}, named:{}, finder:[]}]

Comment: `@UseStringTemplate3StatementLocator
public interface UserDao {
     @SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM t_user <cond>")
     @Mapper(UserMapper.class)
     List<User> fetch(@Define("cond") String cond);
    }`

Answer (score 1):

You must use annotation **@UseStringTemplate3StatementLocator** for DAO interface.
Then you can use "dynamic" sql with `<arg>` syntax:

```
@UseStringTemplate3StatementLocator
public interface UserDao {
   @SqlQuery("SELECT FROM `t_user` <cond>")
   @Mapper(UserMapper.class)
   List<User> fetch(@Bind("cond") String cond);
}
```

For working @UseStringTemplate3StatementLocator annotation project need **antlr:stringtemplate** maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>antlr</groupId>
  <artifactId>stringtemplate</artifactId>
  <version>3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've written a Freemarker integration module for JDBI which can dynamically generate SQL, as opposed to the simple string replacement functionality JDBI provides using @Define.

https://github.com/jhsheets/jdbi-freemarker